# Android-Annotations and inheritance

Tags: android, android-annotations

i am having trouble with android-annotations and inheritance:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public class TestBaseFragment {
    @AfterViews
    public void afterTestBaseFragmentViews() {
   }
}

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public class TestFragment extends TestBaseFragment {
    @AfterViews
    public void afterTestFragmentViews() {
   }
}
```

generates:

```
public final class TestFragment_
    extends TestFragment
{
    ...

    private void afterSetContentView_() {
        afterTestFragmentViews();
        afterTestBaseFragmentViews();
    }
    ...
```

how can I make sure that afterTestBaseFragmentViews() is called before afterTestFragmentViews() ?
Or can you point me to any document which describes how to do inheritance with AndroidAnnotations?

Comment: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/810#issuecomment-31218529

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It's just some sort of workaround**

Using an abstract class:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public abstract class TestBaseFragment {

    @AfterViews
    protected void afterTestBaseFragmentViews() {
        // do something
        afterView();
    }

    protected abstract void afterView();

}

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public class TestFragment extends TestBaseFragment {

    @Override
    protected void afterView() {
        // do something after BaseFragment did something
    }

}
```

Using simple subclassing:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public class TestBaseFragment {

    @AfterViews
    protected void afterTestBaseFragmentViews() {
        afterView();
    }

    public void afterView() {
        // do something
    }

}

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_foo)
public class TestFragment extends TestBaseFragment {

    @Override
    public void afterView() { 
        super.afterView();
        // do something after BaseFragment did something
    }

}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. (Not tested - just written in notepad)

Comment: method ```afterTestBaseFragmentViews``` should not be private. In this case AA can't access this method

Comment: what if TestBaseFragment has annotations like ViewById ? In my case, these annotations are not seen in the generated class TestFragment_. The same for annotation Click.